# Why doesn't addition/subtraction symbol string splitting not work?

Tags: java, arrays, calculator

Ok so I'm trying to make a command line calculator where it detects if your trying to add/subtract/multiply/divide using the String.contains method. Multiplication and division work just fine, but when I try to add or subtract, it spits out a bunch of errors. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatorCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true){
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             String userinput = input.nextLine();
    if(userinput.contains("x")){    
        String[] multiply = userinput.split("x");
        String multiply1 = multiply[0];
        String multiply2 = multiply[1];
        double a = Double.parseDouble(multiply1);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(multiply2);
        double multoutput = a * b;
        System.out.println(a + "x" + b + "=" + multoutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("/")){
        String[] divide = userinput.split("/");
        String divide1 = divide[0];
        String divide2 = divide[1];
        double c = Double.parseDouble(divide1);
        double d = Double.parseDouble(divide2);
        double divideoutput = c/d;
        System.out.println(c + "/" + d + "=" + divideoutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("-")){
        String[] subtract = userinput.split("-");
        String subtract1 = subtract[1];
        String subtract2 = subtract[2];
        double e = Double.parseDouble(subtract1);
        double f = Double.parseDouble(subtract2);
        double suboutput = e - f;
        System.out.println(e + "-" + f + "=" + suboutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("+")){
        String[] add = userinput.split("+");
        String add1 = add[1];
        String add2 = add[2];
        double g = Double.parseDouble(add1);
        double h = Double.parseDouble(add2);
        double addoutput = g - h;
        System.out.println(g + "-" + h + "=" + addoutput);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors for addition:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1878)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2292)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2334)
    at CalculatorCode.main(CalculatorCode.java:36)
```

Subtraction Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at CalculatorCode.main(CalculatorCode.java:29)
```

Comment: please share yur error as well

Comment: For more efficiency use nested if else,dont use only if statements

Comment: What is your input and what is your expected output??.. is your input somethinglike 5+4, 3-1 ??

Comment: When you find that you're duplicating code, it's a good thing to put it into a method

Comment: In all 5 of your questions, you never accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change your code to below .You have used the array indexes wrongly.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatorCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true){
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             String userinput = input.nextLine();
    if(userinput.contains("x")){    
        String[] multiply = userinput.split("x");
        String multiply1 = multiply[0];
        String multiply2 = multiply[1];
        double a = Double.parseDouble(multiply1);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(multiply2);
        double multoutput = a * b;
        System.out.println(a + "x" + b + "=" + multoutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("/")){
        String[] divide = userinput.split("/");
        String divide1 = divide[0];
        String divide2 = divide[1];
        double c = Double.parseDouble(divide1);
        double d = Double.parseDouble(divide2);
        double divideoutput = c/d;
        System.out.println(c + "/" + d + "=" + divideoutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("-")){
        String[] subtract = userinput.split("\\-");
        String subtract1 = subtract[0];
        String subtract2 = subtract[1];
        double e = Double.parseDouble(subtract1);
        double f = Double.parseDouble(subtract2);
        double suboutput = e - f;
        System.out.println(e + "-" + f + "=" + suboutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("+")){
        String[] add = userinput.split("\\+");
        String add1 = add[0];
        String add2 = add[1];
        double g = Double.parseDouble(add1);
        double h = Double.parseDouble(add2);
        double addoutput = g + h;
        System.out.println(g + "+" + h + "=" + addoutput);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you test this, then promise me that it works, I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Thank Lakshmi, I didn't realize the addition and subtraction arrays were incorrect. Subtraction works now but addition still doesn't work.

Comment: @Lakshmi - Not in contains() change it to "\\+" in split()

Comment: Did  you test it?  If you post code that you didn't test, you risk getting MORE downvotes.

Comment: @TheLostMind changed it sorry :(

Comment: @DavidWallace will make sure i dont repest it again thnks :)

Comment: @user3147338 the answer is fine now. Please re check.

Comment: You've tested it now, have you?  Promise?

Comment: @Lakshmi provided code doesn't still doesn't work. When I put the input "10+10" it doesn't give any output at all. Subtractions fine tho

Comment: OK.  I promised you that if you tested it and told me that it worked, I would remove my downvote.  I've done that.

Comment: @user3147338 for me it works i give 6+5 it gives 6.0+5.0=11.0 check where you have escaped the + in split function also check double addoutput = g + h;

Comment: @user3147338 glad it is fixed. Accept the answer if it works.

Comment: +1, @Lakshmi and let me apologise for being such a harsh teacher.

Comment: @DavidWallace never mind i was wrong anyways thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @DavidWallace check mike's answer.Its the combination of all the answer posted over here

Comment: @downvoter again negative vote without any explanation? does anybody care to explain why?

Answer (score 2):

check this lines in add and subtract

```
String add1 = add[1];
        String add2 = add[2];
```

array index starts from 0

Looking into other multiplications and dividing statements from your post I assume that you are passing 3 charcters
Thats why you are getting  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

try with this

```
String add1 = add[0];
        String add2 = add[1];
```

Similarily for the subtractions use this

```
String subtract1 = subtract[0];
        String subtract2 = subtract[1];
```

after changing the above two lines your full code will be like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatorCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true){
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             String userinput = input.nextLine();
    if(userinput.contains("x")){    
        String[] multiply = userinput.split("x");
        String multiply1 = multiply[0];
        String multiply2 = multiply[1];
        double a = Double.parseDouble(multiply1);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(multiply2);
        double multoutput = a * b;
        System.out.println(a + "x" + b + "=" + multoutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("/")){
        String[] divide = userinput.split("/");
        String divide1 = divide[0];
        String divide2 = divide[1];
        double c = Double.parseDouble(divide1);
        double d = Double.parseDouble(divide2);
        double divideoutput = c/d;
        System.out.println(c + "/" + d + "=" + divideoutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("-")){
        String[] subtract = userinput.split("-");
        String subtract1 = subtract[0];
        String subtract2 = subtract[1];
        double e = Double.parseDouble(subtract1);
        double f = Double.parseDouble(subtract2);
        double suboutput = e - f;
        System.out.println(e + "-" + f + "=" + suboutput);
            }
    if(userinput.contains("+")){
        String[] add = userinput.split("+");
        String add1 = add[0];
        String add2 = add[1];
        double g = Double.parseDouble(add1);
        double h = Double.parseDouble(add2);
        double addoutput = g - h;
        System.out.println(g + "-" + h + "=" + addoutput);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please use nested `if else` for better efficiency.May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169249/why-we-use-if-else-if-instead-of-multiple-if-block-if-the-body-is-a-return-stat) will help you to know more

Also as other answer suggests you need to escape `-` and `+`

Answer (score 2):

**-** Your problem here are special symbols like `+` and `-`.

**-** You need to use `escape characters` to eradicate these errors.

**Eg:**

**prefix** them with `\\`

```
\\+ and \\-
```

Comment: "-" is fine, but "+" needs to be escaped.

Comment: Yes, but the string is being interpreted as a regex pattern. Though I imagine `Pattern.quote` would suffice here.

Comment: also Op need to look into the array index

Answer (score 1):

[Because the + character is a special character in regular expressions.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

You'll need to escape the `+` in your call to `split()`. Note that you'll need two backslashes since a single backslash is used for escape sequences such as a new-line and tab character.

Example:

```
String[] add = userinput.split("\\+");
```

Answer (score 1):

characters like + , - are used for regex patterns hence you get the dangling meta character exception. Instead you can try to use StringTokenizer. For eg in your case for addition:-

```
 if(userinput.contains("+")){
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(userinput, "+");
        double addedNumber = 0;
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            String add = st.nextToken();
            addedNumber = addedNumber+Double.parseDouble(add);
        }
        System.out.println("Your result is:- "+addedNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
String add1 = add[1];
String add2 = add[2];
// and
String subtract1 = subtract[1];
String subtract2 = subtract[2];
```

but you are supposed to be using (just like with multiplication/divison):

```
String add1 = add[0];
String add2 = add[1];
// and
String subtract1 = subtract[0];
String subtract2 = subtract[1];
```

---

Also, these lines:

```
double addoutput = g - h;
System.out.println(g + "-" + h + "=" + addoutput);
```

are for adding, so you should change them to:

```
double addoutput = g + h;
System.out.println(g + "+" + h + "=" + addoutput);
```

---

Finally, `+` is a special character that needs to be escaped with a `\\`

So you need to change this:

```
String[] add = userinput.split("+");
```

to this:

```
String[] add = userinput.split("\\+");
```

Comment: @JqueryLearner I don't care. You also pasted all of his code back for no reason, still with two errors, which I have mentioned in my edit.

Comment: I dont copy others answers.i have pasted all the code after explaining what to change and where to change.Check lakshmi answer,Its perfect.Also my answer was before Op posted the stacktrace

Comment: @JqueryLearner Neither do I. I post answers specifically showing what is wrong and needs to be changed. He posted the entire class. That's fine and all, but it's verbose. Just because I posted after someone else doesn't mean I copied anyone. I did all of this myself in my own testing workspace.

Comment: may be you might have copied others answers but if you are answer is similar to other answers then I think its just a copy unless your reason is different from the others.I can just say this is the **combination of all the answers** posted over here

Comment: It's a good answer.  Who cares whether he copied others or not?

Answer (score 0):

use try catch block to find where exactly the issue is.
I guess problem might be due to space or termination character in input. Like "2 + 3" or "2+3\0" instead of "2+3"

Array index starts with 0. I guess u know that. :)