# Regex to find the position of a character

Tags: java, regex

I have to find the occurrence of * in a String and based on the position of the * in the string certain operations have to be performed.

```
if(* found in the beginning of the String) {
 do this
}
if(* found in the middle of the String) {
 do this
}
if(* found at the end of the String) {
 do this
}
```

I used `matcher.find()` option but it is not giving the desired result.

Comment: Why haven't you use `indexOf()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: method to get position of a match in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string)

Comment: "it is not giving the desired result" What result is it giving you? For what input? What is the desired result?

Comment: Question already answered. Just for information you should consider using "else if" . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169249/why-we-use-if-else-if-instead-of-multiple-if-block-if-the-body-is-a-return-stat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `String.indexOf`:

```
int pos = str.indexOf('*');
if (pos == 0) {
  // Found at beginning.
} else if (pos == str.length() - 1) {
  // Found at end.
} else if (pos > 0) {
  // Found in middle.
}
```

An alternative would be to use `startsWith`/`endsWith`/`contains`:

```
if (str.startsWith('*')) {
  // Found at beginning.
} else if (str.endsWith('*')) {
  // Found at end.
} else if (str.contains('*')) {
  // Found in middle.
}
```

which might be *marginally* more efficient, since it avoids having to check the entire string in the case that it ends with `*`. However, readability of the code should be the primary concern in selecting between these two, since the performance difference would be negligible in many cases.

And, of course, you don't get the actual position of the `*` if you use the latter approach. It depends upon what you are really trying to do as to whether that matters.

Comment: startsWith("") endsWith("") may also be useful.

Comment: @Fundhor well yes, but you'd also need `contains` in that list too if you are going to mention those. Feel free to add an answer of your own, it's a valid approach.

Comment: nope, your answer is good, no point to add my own. It's just that it can be useful in different circonstances (for information).

Comment: @Fundhor I've added that approach too.

Comment: I'm quite happy that this answer doesn't try to misuse regex, like OP wanted :).

Comment: @Tom I find that the best approach to "how to use regexes to..." questions is usually "don't".

Comment: Also I have a hard question about regex, May you please take a look at [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406286/how-to-prevent-of-re-replacing-by-second-regex) ?